# Selenium WebDriver in C# and CefSharp

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, cefsharp, browser-automation

I just got recently into C# and Selenium as I am trying to realize a little side-project for myself.

I want to create a C# project, with an embedded Chrome Browser (CefSharp), storing cookies and using Selenium for automating a task.

So far I just created two projects, one CefSharp and one Selenium for the task automation. Question is now, how can I connect those into one project? Which driver is necessary and how can the web driver (and which?) connect to the embedded CefSharp?

Thanks

Comment: Selenium is used to automate a web browser using a driver. I'm not sure if there is a driver for CefSharp but it surely there's one for Chrome. Why don't you start over with a console project that uses the NuGet packages `Selenium.WebDriver` and `Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver`? It uses your existing web browser.

Comment: CefSharp is just a wrapper around the Chromium embedded framework,  start by reading https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/UsingChromeDriver.md